# "Root element is missing" Soap Request in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, soap

I have SOAP webservice and I tried connect it. But SOAP response contains that "System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing."

My obj-c code. What's wrong?

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                         "<soap:Body>"
                         "<Method1 xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                         "<param1>string</param1>"
                         "</Method1>"
                         "</soap:Body>"
                         "</soap:Envelope>"];

NSLog(soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"web service url"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];


[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest addValue: @"\"http://tempuri.org/Method1\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                         "<soap:Body>"
                         "<Method1 xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                         "<param1>%@</param1>"
                         "</Method1>"
                         "</soap:Body>"
                         "</soap:Envelope>",str];
Str here is a string that you need to pass for param1.
Hope This will work for you.
```

Comment: I already know how can I use it. I use "string" pseudo code maybe. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the extra quotations from:

```
[theRequest addValue: @"\"http://tempuri.org/Method1\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
```

it should read:

```
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/Method1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help :(